# Response.Write to a String - ASP Classic

Tags: asp-classic

I have an SQL query which retrieves values from a database using a Do Until Loop. The value of SQLCondition inside the loop displays correctly, but if I want to display the value outside the Loop, it doesn't work:

```
If rReseller > 0 Then
    sql2 = "SELECT rl.countryid FROM reseller_locator rl WHERE rl.resellerid = " & rReseller & " AND rl.countryid <> '" & iCountryID & "'"

    'response.write sql2
    Set rsResellerLocator=Conn.Execute(sql2)

    If not rsResellerLocator.EOF Then 

        do until rsResellerLocator.eof  

            iRCountryID = rsResellerLocator("countryid")
            SQLCondition = iRCountryID & ", "

            response.write SQLCondition

        rsResellerLocator.movenext
        loop    

    Else
        SQLCondition = ""
    End If  
        response.write SQLCondition
End If
```

The response.write from inside the loop displays "2,3,4,5". But the response.write from outside the loop displays "5".

How can I store that value from inside the loop into string to be used outside the query?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the inner loop is working as desired? I see no reason why it will display "2,3,4,5" - the way your code is now, it would always just display a single number. Try this:

Replace

```
SQLCondition = iRCountryID & ", "
```

With

```
SQLCondition = SQLCondition  & ", " & iRCountryID
```

That will save the string of conditions, otherwise you're just saving the latest condition

Answer (score 0):

Use this too save need data in string

```html
If rReseller > 0 Then
    sql2 = "SELECT rl.countryid FROM reseller_locator rl WHERE rl.resellerid = " & rReseller & " AND rl.countryid <> '" & iCountryID & "'"

    'response.write sql2
    Set rsResellerLocator=Conn.Execute(sql2)

    If not rsResellerLocator.EOF Then 

        do until rsResellerLocator.eof  

            iRCountryID = rsResellerLocator("countryid")
            SQLCondition = iRCountryID & ", "
    
     SQLConditionAll=""&SQLConditionAll&""&SQLCondition&""
    
            response.write SQLCondition

        rsResellerLocator.movenext
        loop    

    Else
        SQLCondition = ""
    End If  
        response.write SQLCondition
End If
```

Now you can use Response.write SQLConditionAll
 Too show need data in string